# Why the timet count backwards not showing the counting on the label?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the top of form1 i have:

```
private int seconds;
private int minutes;
private int hours;
```

In the constructor:

```
seconds = 0;
minutes = 20;
hours = 0;
label9.Visible = false;
label9.Text = "00:00:00";
```

Then the timer 3 tick event. I used a breakpoint on the timer3 tick event i see that the minutes and seconds are coundting backwards but label 9 is not updating.

Maybe the string.Format on label9 is not right ?

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Verify if the time didn't pass.
            if ((minutes == 0) && (hours == 0) && (seconds == 0))
            {
                // If the time is over, clear all settings and fields.
                // Also, show the message, notifying that the time is over.
                timer3.Enabled = false;
                label9.Visible = true;
                label9.Text = "00:00:00";
            }
            else
            {
                // Else continue counting.
                if (seconds < 1)
                {
                    seconds = 59;
                    if (minutes == 0)
                    {
                        minutes = 59;
                        if (hours != 0)
                            hours -= 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        minutes -= 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                    seconds -= 1;
                // Display the current values of hours, minutes and seconds in
                // the corresponding fields.
                label7.Visible = true;
                label9.Visible = true;
                label9.Text = string.Format("{00} : {00} : {00}", hours.ToString(), minutes.ToString(),seconds.ToString());
            }
        }
```

All i see in the end on label 9 is: 0:0:0 thats it and i dont see 20 minutes counting backward.

Comment: Why aren't you just creating a `Stopwatch`, subtracting the elapsed time from a `TimeSpan` of 20 minutes, and then formatting that? Doing all this manual work feels like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: Maybe cross-thread concurrency has a place?

Comment: How is your `timer3` defined (Interval, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your string formatting, that's the culprit:

```
label9.Text = string.Format("{0:00} : {1:00} : {2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Also - consider using some other mechanism (e.g. `Stopwatch` class) for calculating elapsed time; you can't guarantee that the code as written will execute exactly every 1000 ms.